# Basic Oracle Trigger audit table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having this error and do not know how to fix the error.so please help me.

Error(8,11): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Error(10,26): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEWRETAILPRICE": invalid identifier

Error(17,8): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Error(19,57): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NEWRETAILPRICE": invalid identifier

Error(25,6): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Error(27,26): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "OLDRETAILPRICE": invalid identifier

My code is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER product_audit
    BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON DD_Products
    FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
       Var_ChangeType CHAR(1);

  BEGIN

    IF INSERTING THEN
          VAR_ChangeType := 'I';
          INSERT INTO DD_PriceChange
          (PriceChangeNo, Change_Type, ChangeBy, ChangeDate, 
         NewProductPrice,NewRetailPrice)
         VALUES (ProductHistory_SEQ.NEXTVAL, VAR_ChangeType, USER, SYSDATE,
            :NEW.ProductPrice,  :NEW.RetailPrice);

      ELSIF UPDATING THEN
      VAR_ChangeType := 'U';

       INSERT INTO DD_PriceChange
     (PriceChangeNo, Change_Type, ChangeBy, ChangeDate, 
         OldProductPrice,OldRetailPrice,NewProductPrice,NewRetailPrice)
   VALUES (ProductHistory_SEQ.NEXTVAL, VAR_ChangeType, USER, SYSDATE,
           :OLD.ProductPrice,  :OLD.RetailPrice,:NEW.ProductPrice,  :NEW.RetailPrice);

        ELSE
         VAR_ChangeType := 'D';
     INSERT INTO DD_PriceChange
    (PriceChangeNo, Change_Type, ChangeBy, ChangeDate, 
         OldProductPrice,OldRetailPrice)
   VALUES (ProductHistory_SEQ.NEXTVAL, VAR_ChangeType, USER, SYSDATE,
           :OLD.ProductPrice,  :OLD.RetailPrice);
    END IF;

  END; 
  /
```

I created a table like this

```
 Create table DD_PriceChange
 (
      PriceChangeNo NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY, 
      Change_Type CHAR(1), 
      ChangeBy VARCHAR2(20),
      ChangeDate DATE, 
      OldProductPrice NUMBER(5),
      NewProductPrice NUMBER(5),
      OldRetailPrice NUMBER(5),
      NewRetailPrice NUMBER(5)
 );
```

and

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ProductHistory_SEQ;
```

Does anybody know why I am getting this error please.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why you were getting the error but I stripped everything back and rebuilt the trigger from the basics and got this to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER product_audit
  BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON DD_Products
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  VAR_ChangeType CHAR(1);
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING   THEN VAR_ChangeType := 'I';
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN VAR_ChangeType := 'U';
  ELSE                VAR_ChangeType := 'D';
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO DD_PriceChange
  (
    PriceChangeNo,
    Change_Type,
    ChangeBy,
    ChangeDate, 
    NewProductPrice,
    NewRetailPrice, 
    OldProductPrice,
    OldRetailPrice
  ) VALUES (
    ProductHistory_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
    VAR_ChangeType,
    USER,
    SYSDATE,
    :NEW.ProductPrice,
    :NEW.RetailPrice,
    :OLD.ProductPrice,
    :OLD.RetailPrice
  );
END product_audit;
/
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/812f8/1/1)