# create audit trail using oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, audit-trail

I am trying to create a trigger that will audit all new and old columns or each row updated, inserted. here is the table

```
ID  NUMBER(10,0)    No      1   
ENTITY_ID   NUMBER(10,0)    No      2   
LOCATION_ID NUMBER(10,0)    Yes     3   
NAME    VARCHAR2(128 CHAR)  No      4   
CREATED_BY  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)  No  'unknown'   5   
UPDATED_BY  VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)  No  'unknown'   6   
TS_CREATED  TIMESTAMP(6)    No  "SYSTIMESTAMP
   "    7
```

I am not sure how to write the trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_security_zones
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON security_zones
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN

END;
```

I also want to use client identifier senbt from application. Here is my audit trail table.

```
ID  NUMBER(10,0)    No      1   
ACTION  VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)   Yes     2   
TABLE_ID    VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)  Yes     3   
OLD_VALUE   VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE) Yes     4   
NEW_VALUE   VARCHAR2(1000 BYTE) Yes     5   
USERNAME    VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)  Yes     6   
TS_UPDATED  TIMESTAMP(6)    No  systimestamp    7
```

Is this a good way to do this? I will then render a view for the user based on each table to show them what has changed.

**UPDATE**

I am trying to achieve something similar to the following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_security_zones
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON security_zones
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    var_action CHAR(1);
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING   THEN var_action := 'INSERT';
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN var_action := 'UPDATE';
    ELSE                var_action := 'DELETE';
    END IF;

    /* loop eahc column in the update or insert or delete statement executed */
    for each col in stmt/row{
    INSERT INTO audit_table
    (
    ACTION,
    TABLE_ID,
    OLD_VALUE,
    NEW_VALUE,
    USERNAME,
    TS_CREATED
    ) VALUES (
    var_action,
    :OLD.ID,
    :OLD.columnVALUE,
    :new.COLUMNVALUE,
    ociidentifier,
    systimestamp
    )
    }
END;
```

**UPDATE2**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_security_zones
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON security_zones
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    var_action CHAR(6);
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING   THEN var_action := 'INSERT';
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN var_action := 'UPDATE';
    ELSE                var_action := 'DELETE';
    END IF;

    IF var_action = 'DELETE' THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_table
        (
            ACTION,
            USERNAME,
            ID,
            O_ENTITY_ID,
            O_LOCATION_ID,
            O_NAME,
            O_CREATED_BY,
            O_UPDATED_BY,
            O_TS_CREATED            
        ) VALUES (
            var_action,
            USERNAME,
            :OLD.ID,
            :OLD.ENTITY_ID,
            :OLD.LOCATION_ID,
            :OLD.NAME,
            :OLD.CREATED_BY,
            :OLD.UPDATED_BY,
            :OLD.TS_CREATED         
        );
    ELSEIF var_action = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_table
        (
            ACTION,
            USERNAME,
            ID,         
            N_ENTITY_ID,
            N_LOCATION_ID,
            N_NAME,
            N_CREATED_BY,
            N_UPDATED_BY
            N_TS_CREATED
        ) VALUES (
            var_action,
            USERNAME,
            :NEW.ID,            
            :NEW.ENTITY_ID,
            :NEW.LOCATION_ID,
            :NEW.NAME,
            :NEW.CREATED_BY,
            :NEW.UPDATED_BY,
            :NEW.TS_CREATED
        );
    ELSEIF var_action = 'UPDATE' THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_table
        (
            ACTION,
            USERNAME,
            ID,
            O_ENTITY_ID,
            O_LOCATION_ID,
            O_NAME,
            O_CREATED_BY,
            O_UPDATED_BY,
            O_TS_CREATED,
            N_ENTITY_ID,
            N_LOCATION_ID,
            N_NAME,
            N_CREATED_BY,
            N_UPDATED_BY
            N_TS_CREATED
        ) VALUES (
            var_action,
            USERNAME,
            :OLD.ID,
            :OLD.ENTITY_ID,
            :OLD.LOCATION_ID,
            :OLD.NAME,
            :OLD.CREATED_BY,
            :OLD.UPDATED_BY,
            :OLD.TS_CREATED,
            :NEW.ENTITY_ID,
            :NEW.LOCATION_ID,
            :NEW.NAME,
            :NEW.CREATED_BY,
            :NEW.UPDATED_BY,
            :NEW.TS_CREATED
        );
    END IF;
END;
```

I get the following errors

```
Error(31,9): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VAR_ACTION" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; 
Error(42,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "N_TS_CREATED" when expecting one of the following:     . ) , @ The symbol "." was substituted for "N_TS_CREATED" to continue. 
Error(54,12): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VAR_ACTION" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; 
Error(71,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "N_TS_CREATED" when expecting one of the following:     . ) , @ The symbol "." was substituted for "N_TS_CREATED" to continue. 
Error(90,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     if
```

**UPDATE3**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_security_zones
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON security_zones
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    var_action CHAR(6);
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING   THEN var_action := 'INSERT';
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN var_action := 'UPDATE';
    ELSE                var_action := 'DELETE';
    END IF;

    IF var_action = 'DELETE' THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_table
        (
            ACTION,
            USERNAME,
            ID,
            O_ENTITY_ID,
            O_LOCATION_ID,
            O_NAME,
            O_CREATED_BY,
            O_UPDATED_BY,
            O_TS_CREATED            
        ) VALUES (
            var_action,
            USERNAME,
            :OLD.ID,
            :OLD.ENTITY_ID,
            :OLD.LOCATION_ID,
            :OLD.NAME,
            :OLD.CREATED_BY,
            :OLD.UPDATED_BY,
            :OLD.TS_CREATED         
        );
    ELSE IF var_action = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_table
        (
            ACTION,
            USERNAME,
            ID,         
            N_ENTITY_ID,
            N_LOCATION_ID,
            N_NAME,
            N_CREATED_BY,
            N_UPDATED_BY,
            N_TS_CREATED
        ) VALUES (
            var_action,
            USERNAME,
            :NEW.ID,            
            :NEW.ENTITY_ID,
            :NEW.LOCATION_ID,
            :NEW.NAME,
            :NEW.CREATED_BY,
            :NEW.UPDATED_BY,
            :NEW.TS_CREATED
        );
    ELSE IF var_action = 'UPDATE' THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_table
        (
            ACTION,
            USERNAME,
            ID,
            O_ENTITY_ID,
            O_LOCATION_ID,
            O_NAME,
            O_CREATED_BY,
            O_UPDATED_BY,
            O_TS_CREATED,
            N_ENTITY_ID,
            N_LOCATION_ID,
            N_NAME,
            N_CREATED_BY,
            N_UPDATED_BY,
            N_TS_CREATED
        ) VALUES (
            var_action,
            USERNAME,
            :OLD.ID,
            :OLD.ENTITY_ID,
            :OLD.LOCATION_ID,
            :OLD.NAME,
            :OLD.CREATED_BY,
            :OLD.UPDATED_BY,
            :OLD.TS_CREATED,
            :NEW.ENTITY_ID,
            :NEW.LOCATION_ID,
            :NEW.NAME,
            :NEW.CREATED_BY,
            :NEW.UPDATED_BY,
            :NEW.TS_CREATED
        );
    END IF;
END;
```

error i get now is

```
Error(90,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     if
```

**UPDATE4**

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_security_zones
  BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON security_zones
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    var_action CHAR(6);
BEGIN
    IF INSERTING   THEN var_action := 'INSERT';
    ELSIF UPDATING THEN var_action := 'UPDATE';
    ELSE                var_action := 'DELETE';
    END IF;

    IF var_action = 'DELETE' THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_table
        (
            ACTION,
            USERNAME,
            ID,
            O_ENTITY_ID,
            O_LOCATION_ID,
            O_NAME,
            O_CREATED_BY,
            O_UPDATED_BY,
            O_TS_CREATED            
        ) VALUES (
            var_action,
            'test',
            :OLD.ID,
            :OLD.ENTITY_ID,
            :OLD.LOCATION_ID,
            :OLD.NAME,
            :OLD.CREATED_BY,
            :OLD.UPDATED_BY,
            :OLD.TS_CREATED         
        );
    ELSIF var_action = 'INSERT' THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_table
        (
            ACTION,
            USERNAME,
            ID,         
            N_ENTITY_ID,
            N_LOCATION_ID,
            N_NAME,
            N_CREATED_BY,
            N_UPDATED_BY,
            N_TS_CREATED
        ) VALUES (
            var_action,
            'test',
            :NEW.ID,            
            :NEW.ENTITY_ID,
            :NEW.LOCATION_ID,
            :NEW.NAME,
            :NEW.CREATED_BY,
            :NEW.UPDATED_BY,
            :NEW.TS_CREATED
        );
    ELSIF var_action = 'UPDATE' THEN
        INSERT INTO audit_table
        (
            ACTION,
            USERNAME,
            ID,
            O_ENTITY_ID,
            O_LOCATION_ID,
            O_NAME,
            O_CREATED_BY,
            O_UPDATED_BY,
            O_TS_CREATED,
            N_ENTITY_ID,
            N_LOCATION_ID,
            N_NAME,
            N_CREATED_BY,
            N_UPDATED_BY,
            N_TS_CREATED
        ) VALUES (
            var_action,
            'test',
            :OLD.ID,
            :OLD.ENTITY_ID,
            :OLD.LOCATION_ID,
            :OLD.NAME,
            :OLD.CREATED_BY,
            :OLD.UPDATED_BY,
            :OLD.TS_CREATED,
            :NEW.ENTITY_ID,
            :NEW.LOCATION_ID,
            :NEW.NAME,
            :NEW.CREATED_BY,
            :NEW.UPDATED_BY,
            :NEW.TS_CREATED
        );
    END IF;
END;
```

new error i get

```
    Error(9,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(19,4): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "O_TS_CREATED": invalid identifier
Error(32,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(42,4): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "N_TS_CREATED": invalid identifier
Error(55,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(71,4): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "N_TS_CREATED": invalid identifier
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020020/basic-oracle-trigger-audit-table) for an example of an audit trigger.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: All I can see wrong in UPDATE2 is a missing comma in the last INSERT between N_UPDATED_BY and N_TS_CREATED

Comment: i have updated it, can you check update3? is my logic correct with the old and new on diffferent actions?

Comment: Instead of `ELSE IF` write `ELSIF` (one word).

Comment: please see update 4

Comment: You need to **look at** these errors rather than just keeping asking!  This is quite simple, a matter if putting something that isn't a column name into the list of columns in your first INSERT...

Comment: working now, i had wrong table

Comment: " i had wrong table" LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "loop" through the OLD and NEW values, you have to reference each one explicitly i.e.

```
INSERT INTO audit_table
    (
    ACTION,
    TABLE_ID,
    OLD_VALUE,
    NEW_VALUE,
    USERNAME,
    TS_CREATED
    ) VALUES (
    var_action,
    :OLD.ID,
    :OLD.column1VALUE,
    :new.COLUMN1VALUE,
    ociidentifier,
    systimestamp
    );
INSERT INTO audit_table
    (
    ACTION,
    TABLE_ID,
    OLD_VALUE,
    NEW_VALUE,
    USERNAME,
    TS_CREATED
    ) VALUES (
    var_action,
    :OLD.ID,
    :OLD.column2VALUE,
    :new.COLUMN2VALUE,
    ociidentifier,
    systimestamp
    );
... etc.
```

You may be able to simplify the code somewhat by writing a procedure to wrap the INSERT statement and calling that many times instead of the INSERT statement itself.